# When uploading a website from WAMP to online, will the php libraries need to be reinstalled, or just be copied over?

Tags: php

I'm upgrading my domain's version of php, and have cloned the website to a WAMP installation on my local machine, so that I can work through the php errors during the upgrade.

When installing the php extensions/libraries in WAMP eg Swiftmailer, I'm using Composer to install. Others I'm installing the .dll file from PECL

How does that installation work when I'm uploading to my test site? ie can the directory structure then be copied over to the online site, or will I need to reinstall the libraries onto the server using a Putty interface etc, then recode any paths in php scripts that are including the php extensions/libraries?

Thank you